# Draw Circle in ImageView when getting current location IndoorAtlas SDK

Tags: android

[image]

I want to get current location and draw blue dot like picture above. The blue dot is moving when the current location change.

Here is my code :

```
public void onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state) {
    mSharedBuilder.setLength(0);
    mSharedBuilder.append("Location: ")
            .append(state.getRoundtrip()).append("ms")
            .append(state.getGeoPoint().getLatitude())
            .append(state.getGeoPoint().getLongitude())
            .append(state.getMetricPoint().getX())
            .append(state.getMetricPoint().getY())
            .append(state.getImagePoint().getI())
            .append(state.getImagePoint().getJ())
            .append(state.getHeadingDegrees())
            .append(state.getUncertainty());
    double x1 = state.getMetricPoint().getX();
    double y1 = state.getMetricPoint().getY();
    float x = (float) x1;
    float y = (float) y1;
    Paint paint = null;
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,1,paint);
}
```

Could you help me ? The pictures already in resource folder.

Answer (score 1):

First, in this case it is easier if you use coordinates from ServiceState#getImagePoint() - these (I & J) are coordinates of your location in the original floor plan. I.e. if your original mapped & uploaded floor plan had dimensions 800x600, service might return position I:400,J:300 indicating that you are now in the center of your mapped area.

You cannot however draw a circle like this: canvas.drawCircle(400, 300, radius, paint) - because depending on how your image is currently displayed (e.g. scaled) you might be drawing into incorrect location.

You need to take into account where your image is on the screen and what are it's current dimensions, i.e. scaling ratio. E.g. if you have a display of size 1920x1080 and your floor plan image of size 800x600 is drawn centered and without any scaling into an ImageView that occupies the entire screen real estate (assume full 1920x1080 in portrait here), then you would need to draw your current coordinate (400,300) into canvas at x: ((1080-800)/2)+400, y: ((1920-600/2)+300) = 540,960.

To draw accuracy with the blue dot (the semi-transparent larger circle), use uncertainty to calculate circle radius.

Comment: FYI: IndoorAtlas has released it's 2.0 SDKs with examples on how to draw location on Google Map or on custom floor plan image. Main docs: http://docs.indooratlas.com/android/, examples in GitHub: https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples. E.g draw location over floor plan bitmap: https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/tree/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/imageview.