# Draw Circle inside bitmap with another method

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Is there any posibilities to draw circle in different method. Here is the step :

1. In onCreate method i call method loadFloorPlanImage(); <--- it is
   using bitmap to draw floor plan that get from IndoorAtlas.
2. Next i want to draw circle inside loadFloorPlanImage method in
   different
       method.

So this is the code :

```
public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
initIndoorAtlas(); <-- cobtain connection with IndoorAtlas.
}
```

Inside initIndoorAtlas(); There is call loadFloorPlan(); method.

```
public void loadFloorPlanImage(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
    FutureResult<Bitmap> result = mIndoorAtlas.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan,options);
    result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                    log("oNResult LoadFloorPlanImage");
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onSystemError(IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onApplicationError(IndoorAtlasException e) {

        }
    });
}
```

Until this i was succed to draw floor plan in UI thread using bitmap. Next i want to draw blue circle to get current location in different method. It's :

```
 public void onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state){
    final double x,y;
    int i,j;
    x = state.getMetricPoint().getX();
    y = state.getMetricPoint().getY();
    i = state.getImagePoint().getI();
    j = state.getImagePoint().getJ();

//here is to draw circle based on i,j pixel.
}
```

Notice that onServiceUpdate(ServiceState state) is giving respons when the Phone is moving.

Is there anyone can help ?

Comment: I think I´d need more detail on what you´re supposed to do with the bitmap. The "from other method" is not enough. Is this some kind of surface updating code??

Comment: this application function is to locating device inside building. It is using indooratlas SDK. The first bitmap is calling floor plan image from indooratlas cloud (LoadFloorPlanImage). Next in onServiceUpdate is auto generating code when the device is moving. And what i want is draw circle when onServiceUpdate doing something. It is like blue dot in google maps.

Answer (score 0):

See the basic math for calculating correct position in your other question: [Draw Circle in ImageView when getting current location IndoorAtlas SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166789/draw-circle-in-imageview-when-getting-current-location-indooratlas-sdk).

The to draw the position, store last location returned from server, call invalidate to the ImageView that you've used to display the floor plan bitmap, override it's onDraw(Canvas), call super.onDraw(canvas) first, then draw the blue dot (using the math as referenced above) with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float, float, float, android.graphics.Paint). You can draw one semi-transparent circle for the accuracy (larger radius) and one circle for the actual blue dot.